# VueJS check if string contains substring in if-statement in v-btn tag

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js, vuetify.js

My goal is to check if the link from a json object contains 'http' if yes, give the v-btn a target='_blank' . It can also be for example a #test link.

How I do it now is:

```
<v-btn
color="primary"
text
:href="x.link"
x.link.includes("http") ? target="_blank" : null
>
    Read more
</v-btn>
```

That gives this error message with an arrow to the first dubble quote by http
`error: Parsing error: unexpected-character-in-attribute-name`

This is what is in x:

```
0:Object
created_at:null
header:"Sport"
id:1
image_large:"https://i.picsum.photos/id/389/800/400.jpg"
image_medium:"https://i.picsum.photos/id/389/600/300.jpg"
image_small:"https://i.picsum.photos/id/389/200/200.jpg"
link:"http://example.com"
submenu:null
updated_at:null
```

Some objs have as link `link:"#test"`

So the code gives an error on the .includes but I can't really find anything that solves this problem or finds a way around it.

I hope my request is clear. Thanks for the help

Comment: How about `:target="x.link.includes('http') ? '_blank' : ''"` ? It's fine if you leave the attribute empty.

Comment: @AurelBílý Thank you that works! If you answer the question I can accept your answer.

Comment: I recommend to use computed ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting JavaScript syntax directly into the "HTML", where it is not interpreted correctly. Not declaring any `target` and setting `target` to the empty string is basically equivalent, so instead you can use the normal `:attribute` syntax to switch between `"_blank"` and `""`:

```html
<v-btn
  color="primary"
  (... other things)
  :target="x.link.includes('http') ? '_blank' : ''"
>
```

(Note the use of single quotes in the actual JS code.)